# Validate goal pose reachability without actually moving

Tags: ros, navigation, planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am aware that sendGoal() method in actionlib::SimpleActionClient can be used for reaching a goal pose. However if the goal is reachable it physically moves to the target pose. I want to know whether there is a method to validate a particular goal pose is reachable without actually moving with ROS navigation stack.

Having it validated with just the global planner is good enough for my purpose. If the goal is considered as reachable at first and then found it is not reachable on the way to it due to recently moved obstacles, an alternative situational decision can be made.

Thanks,

Kalana

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/115736/validate-goal-pose-reachability-without-actually-moving/) by [Kalana](https://answers.ros.org/users/10571/kalana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`move_base` indeed does offer a `make_plan` service for that purpose. See [wiki docs](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base#Services).

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2014-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kalana](https://answers.ros.org/users/10571/kalana/) on 2014-01-09**:
Thanks! make_plan service works fine.